# Unused levels in legend disappear in ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

By using the drop=FALSE option in the scale_fill_manual() function, I am able to include all legend labels - even the ones that are unused in the data. Below is an example of that working. In the below example, there are no cases in the data where count>33; however, there remains a legend label "33+":

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(1)
x = abs(rnorm(100))
y = abs(rnorm(100))
value = runif(100, 1, 30)

myData <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, value=value)

lowVal <- c(1,3,5,9,17,33)
getInterval <- function(input){
  for (i in length(lowVal):1){
    if (input >= lowVal[i]){
      ret = lowVal[i]
      break()
    }
  }
  ret
}
myData$valueColor  <- sapply(myData$value, function(x) getInterval(x))
myData$valueColor = factor(myData$valueColor,levels=lowVal,ordered=TRUE)

for (i in 1:(length(lowVal)-1)){
  levels(myData$valueColor)[i] <- paste0(lowVal[i],"-",lowVal[i+1]-1)
}
levels(myData$valueColor)[length(lowVal)] <- paste0(lowVal[length(lowVal)], "+")

my_breaks = levels(myData$valueColor)
clrs <- brewer.pal(length(my_breaks)+3, "Purples")
clrs <- clrs[3:length(clrs)]

# Static plot
sp <- ggplot(myData, aes(x=x, y=y, counts=value, fill=valueColor)) + geom_area(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(labels = as.character(my_breaks), values = rev(clrs), name = "Cases count", drop = FALSE) + coord_fixed(ratio=1)
sp
```

However, when I attempt to convert this static plot into an interactive plot using ggplotly(), that legend label "33+" disappears:

```
ip <- ggplotly(sp)
ip
```

Is it possible to keep all unused levels in the legend label through ggplotly()?

Side note: There are lots of other problems in this MWE. But this particular question is the only one I am focusing on! Thank you for any advice!

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/556) for this, which may indicate there is no built-in fix right now.

Comment: If you don't mind a hacky way, you could append a list of your own to `ip$x$data` respecting the same structure and have `mylist$legendgroup = "33+"` and `mylist$name = "33+`